# Apache Camel Spring DSL, referring to an environment variable HOSTNAME

Tags: spring, properties, apache-camel, filenotfoundexception

I am using Apache Camel 2.16.0 with Spring DSL 
I have a Spring context XML in which I have defined a Property PlaceHolder to read the properties from various files as follows-

```
    <bean id="propertyPlaceholder" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="systemPropertiesModeName" value="SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_OVERRIDE"/>
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="false"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/properties/versioning.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:/properties/#{inetAddress.hostName}.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="inetAddress" class="java.net.InetAddress" factory-method="getLocalHost"/>
```

The property values are used to construct other beans such as -

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="${${LIVE_}DATASOURCE_URL}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${${LIVE_}DATASOURCE_USERNAME}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${${LIVE_}DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}"/>
</bean>
```

This works fine, I can see the beans being created. 
I also have another Spring Context XML in the same app which has a camel context and I want to use the some other properties defined in the same properties files. I know that camel supports Spring Property Placeholder, see below excerpts from the context -

```
<camelContext id="charge-process-context" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <propertyPlaceholder id="properties" 
        location="classpath:/properties/versioning.properties,
                             properties/${env:HOSTNAME}.properties"
        xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" />
    .....
    .....
</camelContext>
```

As part of this context, I have a route that uses https component that uses the values from the property file such as below -

```
<to uri="https4:{{LIVE_AUTH_RESPONSE_HOST}}:{{LIVE_AUTH_RESPONSE_PORT}}/{{LIVE_AUTH_RESPONSE_CONTEXT_PATH}}"/>
```

This route does not start and throws following exception -

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find system environment with key: HOSTNAME
    at org.apache.camel.util.FilePathResolver.resolvePath(FilePathResolver.java:54)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent.parseLocations(PropertiesComponent.java:434)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent.parseUri(PropertiesComponent.java:163)
    at org.apache.camel.component.properties.PropertiesComponent.parseUri(PropertiesComponent.java:148)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.resolvePropertyPlaceholders(DefaultCamelContext.java:2261)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinitionHelper.resolvePropertyPlaceholders(ProcessorDefinitionHelper.java:730)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createOutputsProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:427)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createOutputsProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:413)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createOutputsProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:165)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ExpressionNode.createFilterProcessor(ExpressionNode.java:109)
    at org.apache.camel.model.WhenDefinition.createProcessor(WhenDefinition.java:74)
    at org.apache.camel.model.WhenDefinition.createProcessor(WhenDefinition.java:32)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.createProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:483)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ChoiceDefinition.createProcessor(ChoiceDefinition.java:135)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessorImpl(ProcessorDefinition.java:534)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:495)
    at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:219)
    at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1069)
```

Please Note: I am deploying my application as a war file on Tomcat 8 on an AWS instance. 
I have a Dev Environment on Windows 10 and I have found this working on the Windows OS. I have also seen that the file FilePathResolver.java in Apache Camel 2.16 uses System.getenv(key) to obtain the value i.e. System.getenv("HOSTNAME") which returns a null on AWS instance and a correct value on Windows 10. I also tried using env:hostname (small case letters for unix) but still no luck ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution at http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html 
at Bridging Spring and Camel Property Placeholders

It mentions following -

The Spring Framework does not allow 3rd party frameworks such as Apache Camel to seamless hook into the Spring property placeholder mechanism. However you can easily bridge Spring and Camel by declaring a Spring bean with the type org.apache.camel.spring.spi.BridgePropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, which is a Spring org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer type.